# AutoLayout fail in Xcode. Disabled it by accident, how to put it back like it was?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, autolayout

I was told that to fix an issue in my Xcode app I could uncheck the "Use auto layout" in the "Interface Builder Document"[image: Use auto layout check]

After doing this my whole app broke. See on the pictures:
[image: Error happening after unchecking auto layout.]
[image]

I tried to activate auto layout back but the app was still broken. I tried to redo the contains but doesn't work. Lost please help.

Comment: This is why you should save your work using SCM (`git` is almost the universal standard by now) :) I don't think there's any way to magically undo all the changes, so use this as an opportunity to learn autolayout, it's awesome!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that layout ;). OK, sorry. Maybe try checking "Use Safe Area Layout Guides" as well, and also, make sure that you are actually adding constraints from your views to the edge, maybe those were deleted when you deleted auto layout support.

Comment: If you disable the autolayout, if you enable it back again, the constraints will be gone. So there's no way on doing that. Not sure if "Undo" will keep track of these changes since XCode has a lot of dumb "Undo" glitches. You should really think about what @GuyKogus said. Even if it's a local repo it still helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for helping. Like some of you said there was anyway to actually bring back the old constraints. 
What I had do do was basically ,view controller by view controller, delete all constraints and put back new ones. Took a while to make it back like it was before but it is possible. 
Thanks Again

Comment: Give git repro a try :) You will never loose so much time in the future.